# How to roll up duplicate observation in pydatatable?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I have a data frame as-

```
my_dt = dt.Frame({'last_name':['mallesh','bhavik','jagarini','mallesh','jagarini'],
                  'first_name':['yamulla','vemulla','yegurla','yamulla','yegurla'],
                  'ssn':['1234','7847','0648','4567','0648']})
```

[image]

Here I would like to find out duplicates considering last_name and firs_name columns and if any duplicates found their respective ssn needs to be rolled up with semicolon(;) if SSN are not different. if SSN are also same only one SSN needs to be present.

the expected output as:

[image]

Here since **mallesh yamulla** is duplicated and has different SSN's they are rolled up with ';'

and in case of **jagarini yegurla** it has a unique SSN hence one SSN is only taken.

Comment: at the moment, string operations in datatable are very limited. You can drop duplicates with a cumulative count, however, for the string operations, you are better served with Pandas

Comment: OK. thanks for that. i'm thinking of going for POLARS

Comment: yea, polars is another exciting library. Hopefully, soon pydatatable will be more robust in terms of features

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by all columns first and then aggregate `join`:

```
df = (my_dt.drop_duplicates()
           .groupby(['last_name','first_name'], sort=False)['ssn']
           .agg(';'.join)
           .reset_index())
print (df)
  last_name first_name        ssn
0   mallesh    yamulla  1234;4567
1    bhavik    vemulla       7847
2  jagarini    yegurla       0648
```

Comment: In Pandas I can get it done. as I'm dealing with higher volumes of data I'm working with pydatatable.

Comment: @myamulla_ciencia - I only removed duplicates by `my_dt[:, first(f[0:]), by([f[0],f[1],f[2]], add_columns=False)]`, but string operation join are not implemented in `datatable`, so cannot do second step. Only way I think is convert to pandas and aggregate join.

Comment: @myamulla_ciencia - I try `sum` by `my_dt[:, [dt.sum(f[2])], by([f[0],f[1]])]`, but it raise error `TypeError: Unable to apply reduce function `sum()` to a column of type `str32``